# How to query from a csv repeatedly throughout the day in a simulation code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, design-patterns

I'm trying to write a simulation code in python. This simulation code relies on inputs for a large csv file, and there is a separate csv file for each day in the simulation. I need to make numerous queries (the queries are based on time, which are columns in the csv file) each simulation day.

I'm thinking of using `pandas.read_csv` to read this in as a dataframe, and store the result and then query from this dataframe. One coding requirement is I don't want the dataframe stored at the query site.

I think the easiest way to do this is with a class, e.g.,

```
import pandas as pd
class DailyCSVLoader:
  def __init__(filepath):
    self.df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
  def query(time):
    # return the rows corresponding to time
```

with usage:

```
import datetime

path = "/path/to/csv/file/filename.csv"
time = datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=1, day=1, hour=12, minute=2, second=0)
loader = DailyCSVLoader(path)
loader.query()
```

However, for my particular codebase, it might be slightly easier to do this outside of a class and with just a function and perhaps a static variable that holds the dataframe, e.g.,

```
import pandas as pd

# because I don't want the calling site to store df, I decided to keep it as a static variable here
def daily_csv_loader(filepath):
  daily_csv_loader.df = pd.read_csv(filepath)


def query(time, df):
  # return rows from df corresponding to time
```

with usage

```
import datetime

path = "/path/to/csv/file/filename.csv"
time = datetime.datetime(year=2020, month=1, day=1, hour=12, minute=2, second=0)
daily_csv_loader(filepath)
query(time, daily_csv_loader.)
```

Are there any other approaches here, preferably a functional approach (I would prefer not to use OOP here as alluded to previously)? Is there a functional approach that can be done with a single function, perhaps with nested functions?

Comment: Is the data static? Is it large? In the simplest case just read all of it into memory at once if you expect to need most of it sooner or later.

Comment: This question needs more focus, "what is the best" questions need to provide  concrete constraints and metrics to compare alternatives. For example, it seems you're looking for "easiness", which is very vague. If you already have something that works, then by one definition of "easy", you're already done.

Comment: @tripleee Yes the data remains the same within each csv file. It is quite large although there are large variances but even in the smallest case we can probably expect O(10^5) rows and around 30 columns

Comment: @Kache I should probably rephrase the question to just look for other solutions besides the one I posted since "best" is subjective. I'll make that edit

Comment: @roulette01 Be specific about the differences you're looking for in these alternatives, or else this will probably get closed for lack of focus. Provide things to narrow down the infinite space of "any alternative". Fewer lines of code? Better performance against a particular benchmark (please provide)? Adhering to OOP/functional style? etc

Comment: @Kache Just updated the OP to make it more specific

Answer (score 2):

An example that is functional-esque, with nested functions, doesn't expose the underlying csv/dataframe object at the callsite, ultimately invoked via a single function:

```py
import csv
import datetime as dt
import io
from typing import Any, Dict

def load_queryable_csv(csv_str):
    # a quick & easy setup, could have used pandas instead and/or generalized parsing
    rows = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(csv_str))
    parsed_rows = [
        {'a': row['a'], 'b': int(row['b']), 'time': dt.datetime.fromisoformat(row['time'])}
        for row in rows
    ]

    # "querying"
    def query_csv(**column_matchers):
        def matcher(row: Dict[str, Any]):
            return all(row[col] == val for col, val in column_matchers.items())

        return list(filter(matcher, parsed_rows))

    return query_csv

query_csv = load_queryable_csv("""\
a,b,time
x,2,2020-01-01 12:02:00
y,4,2020-01-01 12:02:01
""")

time = dt.datetime(year=2020, month=1, day=1, hour=12, minute=2, second=0)

query_csv(time=time)
# => [{'a': 'x', 'b': 2, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 12, 2)}]

query_csv(a='y')
# => [{'a': 'y', 'b': 4, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 12, 2, 1)}]
```